# Create private React library

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have some components made for a React (ES6) application and now I want to share these with some other applications.

How should I setup a repository for this?

- What should webpack.config.js look like?
- How to include SASS?
- How not include node_module files in my dist build? Or maybe just translate es6 to es5 (what would happen with SCSS inports)?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it, is to use the usual process of building with Webpack. You build your project and the output of it will be one JS bundle, and one CSS bundle (your SASS turned into CSS). Then you consume your library's resource, the JS and CSS, from the consuming app.

The important thing here is to make sure that in your `webpack.config.js` file you set output type to `library`:

```
...
output: { 
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "dist/mylib.js",
    library: ["MyLibrary", "mylib"],
    libraryTarget: "umd" 
},
...
```

Then in the consuming app you can reference the JS file and import components from it

```
import {MyComponent} from './mylib';
```

As for CSS, just `<link>` the CSS file in your page the usual way.